# Heartbleed flaw fix on Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, openssl, heartbleed

is there any 100% working method to update openssl to the non vulnerable version on Debian Wheezy.
I do not want to upgrade the whole OS, nor would I like to install a non official package.

Is there any solution right now ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [DSA-2896-1 openssl -- security update](https://www.debian.org/security/2014/dsa-2896) :

> For the stable distribution (wheezy), this problem has been fixed in version 1.0.1e-2+deb7u5.

so,
assuming you have:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
```

in your /etc/apt/sources.list file

```
apt-get update
apt-cache policy openssl
apt-get install openssl
```

`apt-cache policy openssl` will show you candidate updates

`apt-get install openssl` will upgrade to last openssl version

run again `apt-cache policy openssl` and check version at *Installed:* line is equal or superior to: 1.0.1e-2+deb7u5

upgrading openssl package should upgrade libssl1.0.0 as it's a dependency

Comment: I did exactly that but it seems I needed a reboot. Thanks !

Comment: reboot is the safe way. you can avoid reboot by identifying which processes use outdated libs and restart them specifically. `lsof +aL1 /usr | grep ssl` should help you in this quest